# AWS GET request with body rejected by CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I'm build an API using AWS SAM (Lambda & API Gateway) whose contract is defined by a 3rd party.

The 3rd party calls my API with a GET request that contains JSON in the body. However, when a request is sent to the API with a body it gets rejected by CloudFront.

This is the request:

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"hello":"world"}' https://my-api.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Prod/my-api
```

This is the response:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <H1>403 ERROR</H1>
        <H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
        <HR noshade size="1px">
Bad request.


        <BR clear="all">
        <HR noshade size="1px">
        <PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: 1p0St_-e3noQL-2uMxeB_2I6lkMr1mg5afvxJRmVpCdnG67Vgnhj9w==
</PRE>
        <ADDRESS></ADDRESS>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Checking the logs, the request never hits API Gateway or the Lambda function. However, if I remove the body from the request, then it hits the Lambda function and I get the appropriate error message from the API (telling the caller that the expected body is missing.)

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://my-api.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Prod/my-api
```

I'm using basic configuration of API Gateway via a SAM template. This is the relevant section:

```
MyApiFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    CodeUri: bin/main.zip
    Handler: main
    Runtime: go1.x
    Tracing: Active
    Role: !Sub ${MyApiLambdaExecutorRole.Arn}
    Events:
      CatchAll:
        Type: Api
        Properties:
          Path: /my-api
          Method: GET
```

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body).  That is illegal according to the RFC.

Comment: I'm subscribing to a 3rd party's Webhooks and the 3rd party issues this request to verify that my API is responding. I understand the objection to GET requests that contain a body, but I have no control over it. If there is no workaround then my only option is to move my API off AWS entirely.

Comment: I understand your frustration but AWS is implementing the standard.  Try to create some code on an EC2 and maybe you can find something that will allow it.  I know you're caught in the middle but it's going to be a tough one to solve other than to tell the 3rd party that they are breaking things.

Comment: I just proved to myself that, at least in Java with JAX-RS, I can get the body from a GET call.  It's a bit convoluted but it can be done.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`GET` requests cannot contain a request body on CloudFront. Try using `POST` instead.

If you want to send limited data in a `GET` request, you can use query parameters.

You can see in the AWS Docs that this isn't possible here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#RequestCustom-get-body

> If a viewer GET request includes a body, CloudFront returns an HTTP status code 403 (Forbidden) to the viewer.

You could perhaps use an EC2 instance or other service that doesn't use API Gateway to handle the request.

Comment: Thanks, but a 3rd party specifies the API contract, so I cannot change what the request looks like. I can't send a POST or just query parameters instead.

Comment: Then the 3rd party needs to change the contract. Most servers do not support GET requests with a body. That's pretty standard practice.

Comment: You can find more detailed information on the subject here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: Worth noting, there's nothing in the HTTP spec that forbids a body with a GET method, and in fact it's commonly used with some APIs, see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html

Comment: While that may be true, this question is regarding API Gateway which does not allow it.

Comment: The original question does, but not this comment thread.  If you're going to reference a SOF post that talks about the HTTP RFC and talk about "most servers", you open it up to a broader topic.

Comment: Downvoted for 2 reasons: 1) The initial statement and subsequent claim in the comments are incorrect and are directly contradicted by the link shared in the comments. 2) The link in the answer does not contain the provided blockquote at all, nor does it contain any obvious info about support for GET requests with a body.

Comment: Up-to-date link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#RequestCustom-get-body

Comment: Thank you for the updated docs that say "If a viewer GET request includes a body, CloudFront returns an HTTP status code 403 (Forbidden) to the viewer." I will edit my answer