# The request couldn't be satisfied response on GET request

Tags: curl, binance

I am trying to get binance account information using binance api. 
I have a secret key and an api key.

curl

> curl -H "X-MBX-APIKEY: apikeygoeshere" -X GET https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account -d timestamp=1578926101
>   &signature=bbce62e6f607e444063f46ad83b0f4e5859980df717dd8ac436357e1783aa828

**I created signature by using my secret key and this string : "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account&timestamp=1578926101"

**this is the response**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>403 ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
Bad request.
We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
<BR clear="all">
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: nBSblWzZLCEQ6lKHdFL2vA0EOArNa7auab25hmdNvrMwfcZQJaA32w==
</PRE>
<ADDRESS>
</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>gugas-pc:~ guga$ &signature=bbce62e6f607e444063f46ad83b0f4e5859980df717dd8ac436357e1783aa828
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'
```

I am trying to get account information using [binance API](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#signed-trade-user_data-and-margin-endpoint-security)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your Answer:

[CloudFront Bad request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55910096/are-get-request-with-body-allowed-on-aws-403-error-from-cloudfront/55913836#55913836)

You can try query string mentioned in the binance API:

```
curl -vko /dev/null -X GET "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account?timestamp=1578926101&signature=bbce62e6f607e444063f46ad83b0f4e5859980df717dd8ac436357e1783aa828"
```

Comment: In your example, where do I put API key? Also, I am creating a get request using c# and the url I am submitting is this : "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account?timestamp=1579074130&signature=signaturegoeshere". API key is included in request header. 
Am I doing something wrong? I am getting Bad Request error

Comment: You can pass the key as header like -H "X-MBX-APIKEY: apikeygoeshere"  and make sure the data are passed as query string in GET. otherwise, you can make POST request.