# HTTP GET to Binance API via Google Script

Tags: google-sheets, javascript

This might be related to the following [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55910096/are-get-request-with-body-allowed-on-aws-403-error-from-cloudfront/55913836#55913836). I understand that I should not add a BODY to a GET, but it doesn't seem to solve my problem.

I am trying to reach [Binance API's](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#current-average-price) avgPrice through **Google Script**.
The [request](https://api.binance.com/api/v3/avgPrice?symbol=EURUSDT) through my browser works as intended.

This is my code:

```
function averagePrice() 
{
    var key = '***'
    var api = "/api/v3/avgPrice";
    var baseUrl = "https://api.binance.com";
  
    var params = 
    {
      'method': 'GET',
      'headers': {'X-MBX-APIKEY': key},
      'muteHttpExceptions': true
    };

    var url = baseUrl + api + '?symbol=EURUSDT';

    var d = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
    Logger.log(d.getContentText());
}
```

The response I get is as follows:

```
[20-08-06 20:14:14:955 CEST] <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type"CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"><TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H1>403 ERROR</H1><H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2><HR noshade size="1px">Request blocked. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.<BR clear="all">If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.<BR clear="all"><HR noshade size="1px"><PRE>Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront) Request ID: -m-__LPRs7J_orooCPROW2R4JjqiaQGauojl7fEoi2JxDXeIDbwJOQ==</PRE><ADDRESS></ADDRESS></BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint that you are trying to reach requires some type of authorization... Upon further research, it looks like either:

1. You have a typo in the key, or more likely
2. Your account permissions do not allow you to access this particular endpoint.

It seems that their are different access levels associated with user accounts. Read the "API Key Restrictions" section of [this link](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#introduction) for more information.

Also, until you are more familiar with the API, I would suggest downloading the Postman app. It will save you A LOT of time. Binance hase a postman collection of its endpoints, so you can send requests via button clicks instead of via code...

Comment: Hello, thanks for the hint of using Postman. Through Postman my calls are working fine, so it definitely has something to do with permissions, using Google Script through Cloudfront.